# Bootstrap highlight selected item in a nav list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

So I am using bootstrap together with slim to build some navigable pages. Am stuck on highlighting the selected item on the list as "activate" class applied. I did find something called affix or scrollspy but these are different from what I need to do, which is to navigate among pages. I have following code piece:

```
  .container-fluid
      .row-fluid
        .span2
          ul.nav.nav-list
            li.active = link_to 'Home', root_path
            li.divider
            li = link_to 'Openings', openings_path
            ...
        .span10
          ==yield
```

I believe there should be some best practice on this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating pages dynamically, then you can often use your framework to add an **active** class to a menu link. I'm not experienced with ruby on rails, so I can't give you much help there.

There are lots of other ways to achieve the same goal though. For exammple you can add classes to the body tag of your various pages, tweak the HTML for your nav list items, add your CSS styling and you are good to go.

**HTML**

```
<body class="home"> 
or  
<body class="contact">  

<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="home"> <a href="#">home</li>
  <li class="contact"> <a href="#">contact</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.home li.home a, .contact li.contact a{  
background-color#999;
color:white;
}

or if you want to go with the built-in Bootstrap active styling, 
something similar to this:  

.home li.home a, .contact li.contact a,
.home li.home a, .contact li.contact a:hover,
.home li.home a, .contact li.contact a:focus {  
color: #555555;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

You can use this approach for both dynamic and static sites.

Hope this might get you started!